# Double replacement occurring for accented characters when using PXRCHANGE

Tags: sas

I am facing a problem when using `PXRCHANGE` when replacing accented characters such as `ö` with an underscore. More precisely, when I perform the replacement, rather than `ö` being replaced with a single underscore, `_`, it is being replaced with two underscores `__`. This is not just an isolated instance for `ö`, but is occuring for several other accented characters.

Here is some dummy code to replicate my problem:

```
option validvarname = any;
data dummy_data;
    input "ö"n "aü"n;
    datalines;
    1 1
    2 2 
    ;
run;


data badvarnames (keep = name validname);

    set sashelp.vcolumn;
    where libname = "WORK" and memname = "DUMMY_DATA";
    
    validname = prxchange("s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/_/", -1, trim(name));
    name = nliteral(name);
    
run;


proc sql;
    select cats("rename", name, "=", validname, ";") into : renamelist
    separated by " " from badvarnames;
quit;


data output_tab;
    set dummy_data;
    &renamelist.;
run;
```

Comment: If you are interested in a method for "fixing" names check out the method in this %csv2ds() macro.  That also includes code for ensuring the generated names are unique. https://github.com/sasutils/macros/blob/master/csv2ds.sas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex function is treating the multi-byte characters as individual bytes to be replaced. So if the character uses two bytes in UTF-8 then you get two underscores.

Here are two choices.

Use KTRANSLATE() to handle the multi-byte characters.  You can use KCOMPRESS() to find the set of invalid characters in any given name.

```
valid = ' 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
test2 = ktranslate(name,repeat('_',255),kcompress(name,valid));
```

Or replace adjacent invalid characters with a single underscore by adding `+` to your regex.

```
test3 = prxchange("s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/_/", -1, trim(name));
```

Note this will also eliminate the multiple adjacent underscores generated by replacing multiple single byte characters.  So it has the added advantage of making those generated names easier to deal with also.

Comment: I have two questions if that is okay. I understand the logic of using `KTRANSLATE` and `KCOMPRESS` as you have. Does the 225 in `REPEAT` have any specific reason for being chosen, or is it just because it is a sufficiently large enough number of replacements one would be expected to perform? Secondly, I take it the only other way to use `PXRCHANGE` to replace accented characters with single underscores and keep adjacent underscores from replacing multiple single byte characters is to use a different encoder which treats accented characters as a single byte?

Comment: The KTRANSLATE() will replace multi-byte characters with a single character.  255 is just habit as that will generate 256 values which is the max that could exist in single byte character set.  For your application the limit is the length of the orginal string you are trying to "fix".  If it comes from SAS metadata then it will be at most 32 bytes so max 32 characters so use 31 instead of 255.